# Convert ZPL (Base64) in image (PNG)

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, png, zpl

I need to convert a ZPL file into an image. I already use the labelary web service, but I need a solution that is less dependent on an external application.

I am proceeding in the following way. I'm getting the base64 encoded part: eJzs281u4zYQAGAKLMCewmsPhfgaPWipPtIeVUC1GPiQYx6hr9FDgdL....rest of the code (Z64 encoded), which would be the image of the ZPL file, and I'm trying to convert this to a png image. I tried using the code below, but I get this error: Error: Could not find MIME for Buffer

```
const fs = require('fs');
var base64Img = require('base64-img');
var Jimp = require('jimp');

try{
    var data = fs.readFileSync('./test.zpl', 'base64')
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}

var buffer = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');

Jimp.read(buffer).then(res => {
    return res
    .quality(50)
    .rotate(90)
    .resize(250,250)
    .writeAsync('out.png');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I tried using this method too, but it generates a png image, but it cannot be processed by the image viewer.

```
const fs = require('fs');
var base64Img = require('base64-img');

try{
    var data = fs.readFileSync('./test.zpl', 'base64')
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}

var buffer = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');

fs.writeFileSync("./out.png", buffer);
```

Grateful.

Comment: Z64 uses base64 ascii armor over zlib-deflated image data.  So you need to `zlib.inflateSync()` the buffer after the base64 decode.  But what format is the image data?  Is it already a PNG image or is it ZPL's native GRF bitmap format?

Comment: @MarkWarren It's ZPL's native GRF bitmap format. The first line in the ZPL file ^GFA,393088,393088,00148,:Z64:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a GRF (which is a header-less 1-bit bitmap), you will need a png-writing library to create the image - pngjs is the usual one to pull in:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
      zlib = require('zlib'),
      PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;


let match = /(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),:Z64:([^:]+):/
                  .exec(fs.readFileSync('test.zpl', 'ascii'));
let size = +match[1];
let rowl = +match[3];
let grf = zlib.inflateSync(Buffer.from(match[4], 'base64'));

// These values are from the ^GF command
const png = new PNG({
    width: rowl * 8,
    height: size / rowl,
    filterType: -1
});

let offs = 0;
let data = png.data;
for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let byte = grf[i];
    for (let bit = 0x80; bit; bit = bit >>> 1) {
        let bw = (bit & byte) ? 0 : 255; // black (0) or white (255)
        data[offs++] = bw;
        data[offs++] = bw;
        data[offs++] = bw;
        data[offs++] = 255;  // fully opaque
    }
}

png.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.png'));
```

That is from memory and some cut and paste of existing code, so there could be a typo...

Comment: Thank you very much for the provision. It worked here. Just out of curiosity, could you explain this part of the code to me? I'm new in this field and wanted to learn more. Grateful

Comment: let offs = 0;
let data = png.data;
for (let i = 0; i < 393088; i++) {
    let byte = grf[i];
    for (let bit = 0x80; bit; bit = bit >>> 1) {
        let bw = (bit & byte) ? 0 : 255; // black (0) or white (255)
        data[offs++] = bw;
        data[offs++] = bw;
        data[offs++] = bw;
        data[offs++] = 255;  // fully opaque
    }
}

Comment: pngjs uses an RGBA buffer to store its pixel data - similar to the html canvas element.  Every four bytes of the buffer are the red, green, blue, and alpha values for a pixel.  OTOH, GRF is a 1-bit depth bitmap.  Every bit in the data represents either a black (1) or white (0) pixel.  So the outer loop runs through each byte in the GRF data.  The inner loop runs through the 8 bits in the given byte, from left to right.  The `>>>` operator simply shifts the mask bit right on each iteration.

Comment: Inside the loop, the `bw` variable is assigned either 0 or 255 based on whether the current bit in the byte is 1 or 0.  And then the rest just fills in the RGBA value for the corresponding pixel in the pngjs buffer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. It got a little clearer. I'll do some more studying on that. Do you have any material that I can study this subject? Grateful